# ¿Porque una aplicacion de Ionic 2, la barra de estado no cambia?

Tags: ionic, ionic2, plugin, material-design, design

Que tal, quisiera saber el porque la barra de estado de una app de ionic 2, no aplica el estilo de material designer, como otras app.
O hay que agregar algun plugin para que esto suceda?
Si alguien, sabe se lo agradezco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La barra de estado se ajusta en Ionic de la siguiente manera:

1. Instalar las dependencias del plugin [status bar Ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/).
2. Verificar que este correctamente agregado en los *providers* de `~/src/app/app.module.ts`:

   ```
   import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
   ...
   providers: [StatusBar]
   ...
   ```
3. En el archivo `~/src/app/app.component.ts` agregar en `platform.ready()` lo siguiente:

   ```
   ...
   import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";

   @Component({
     templateUrl: "app.html"
   })
   export class MyApp {
     ...

     constructor(statusBar: StatusBar) {
       platform.ready().then(() => {
         statusBar.styleLightContent();
         statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#3c5ed5");
         ...
       });
     }
   }
   ```

> `statusBar.styleLightContent()` es para cambiar el color de los iconos a blanco, en caso de que el color lo necesite, si se omite este método los iconos serán de color gris oscuro.

[Documentación plugin Status Bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/)

Comment: gracias por la reespuesta, ya resolvi el problema. no es cosa de material designer.

Answer (score 1):

Por norma al crear una aplicacion con el cli de ionic te añade ya el plugin StatusBar de cordova.

github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/

Una vez añadido basta con agregar el color que quieras en la etiqueta StatusBarBackgroundColor en tu fichero config.xml

Comment: gracias por la reespuesta, ya resolvi el problema. no es cosa de material designer.